# Node js server doesn't show images in html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to use node js to show an image within an html file, but the image doesn't show up.
If I try to open the html file with a browser the image shows up without problem, but when I run it from the node js server it doesn't work.

Here is my node js code:

```
var http = require('http');  
var fs = require('fs'); 

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
  fs.readFile('pruebaFoto.html', function(err, data) { 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
    res.write(data); 
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equi="refresh" content="1"> <!--I use this meta tag for refreshing the page each second-->
</head>
<body>
<h1>Image: </h1>
<img src="./image.jpg" alt="image">
</body>
</html>
```

The image and all the code are in the same path.

Comment: your server returns `pruebaFoto.html` regardless of what is requested

Comment: There is no code for reading and returning anything else than `pruebaFoto.html`. Regardless of what request you make, you'll always get that html back ...

Comment: Can you specify what you mean? I'm new with node js

Comment: your server only responds with one response ... `pruebaFoto.html` ... regardless of the request - what code would respond with the content of `./image.jpg`?

Comment: @derpirscher shouldn't the image in the html show up?

Comment: No, it's on the server, it's not in the HTML file ... the browser will request it for you

Comment: @FaustoSánchezHoya No, the server can only send back what it reads. And the only thing it reads (regardless of the request you send) is that html file. There is literally no code on the server, which will read the jpg

Comment: So if I want to show the image I must read it first apart from the html?

Comment: when a html file is loaded, the external resources (images, scripts, stylesheets etc) are requested *by the browser* in a separate request

Comment: @Bravo but if it is the browser who request the resources why it doesn't find the image?

Comment: because the *server* is the *server* you wrote, and the browser is looking for the resource on your *server*  - and you wrote it so all requests get the same response - the html file

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a router so the server can respond to different requests with different content.

There are many options for this, a popular option is to use a library like https://expressjs.com/